# Possible to connect to Remote Desktop with PHP?

Tags: php, rdp

I've got a few servers that I'd like to connect to every so often to run a program. However, to make it easier, I'd like to make a PHP script connect to each of them via remote desktop and run each of them. Is this possible? If so, where should I start? An example would be lovely.

Comment: You want to use RDP to connect to and run a PHP script on a server? I could see a VPN/SSH session.

Comment: Yes, its possible, but php script will not be easier than other means like c++ or some shell script

Comment: Maybe this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sam.php

Comment: Worst case you can just open a socket through PHP and communicate back and forth. You'd need to reverse engineer/implement the protocol though. There should be a better solution for that, like a cron job/scheduler on the server itself.

Comment: @deceze yeah, I thought about just opening up a socket, but didn't want to take the time to sniff the connection and reconstruct a normal connection just yet, in case there's a simpler way to do it

Comment: What kind of remote desktop protocol? How are programs invoked? By a click? What kind of operating system(s) is this about?

Comment: Windows Server 2003 and 2008. I imagine by a click, yes, but I'm sure there's a way to emulate that.

Comment: I have translated your request to mean: php code that is an RDP-style server. With that in mind, even though his response didn't answer your question, I am in agreement with @Timur. It might not be as complicated as some naysayers have indicated. Write a php script that captures the foreground window (or pieces of it) and sends the image to the webpage. Make the webpage capture mouse click coordinates and keystrokes, and pipes them from ajax through php and to the foreground window. Recapture the foreground window every so often, and BAM - remote desktop via PHP. I think it's a stellar idea.

Answer (score 9):

In theory you could implement a PHP script that could communicate with a server in the RDP protocol, but I certainly wouldn't want to try to build a script that can do anything meaningful, as RDP is built to expose a remote machine's user interface to the connected client and PHP is built first and foremost to manipulate text.

If you want a PHP script to remotely control another computer, then SSH is a far more sensible option, as PHP could easily connect to the remote cmputer's CLI and issue commands to the server via shell commands, which are textual and therefore easily generated with PHP.

On the other hand, interfacing with the remote computer with RDP would be extremely difficult.  Just think about clicking on an icon to get a directory listing for a start.  You'd first have to determine where the mouse pointer is, whether the icon you want to click is visible and if so where its bounding box is relative to the mouse pointer.  You'd then have to issue commands to move the mouse pointer to within the bounding box, then check that the mouse pointer is in the right place (a local or other remote user might be moving the mouse around) and then issue a pair of clicks with a short delay between them.

That's going to be a lot harder than issuing "cd C:\Program Files\" followed by "dir", for example.

Comment: To further compound the difficulty, even if the RDP protocol was reverse engineered and the PHP script was moving a mouse to known coordinates... the display settings that RDP uses can be inconsistent, so there would be no guarantee that an icon would be located in the same location every session.  The hypothetical script may end up just sending clicks to a dead spot on the screen.

Answer (score 3):

No PHP cannot use RDP to connect to the server. They can use SSH or FTP or a socket to a listening port.

What you are asking is kinda crazy!!! =)

Edit:

Since you insist on doing it here is what you need:

```
[MS-RDPBCGR]: Remote Desktop Protocol: Basic Connectivity and Graphics Remoting Specification
[MS-RDPCR2]: Remote Desktop Protocol: Composited Remoting V2 Specification
[MS-RDPEA]: Remote Desktop Protocol: Audio Output Virtual Channel Extension
[MS-RDPEAI]: Remote Desktop Protocol: Audio Input Redirection Virtual Channel Extension
[MS-RDPECLIP]: Remote Desktop Protocol: Clipboard Virtual Channel Extension
[MS-RDPEDC]: Remote Desktop Protocol: Desktop Composition Virtual Channel Extension
[MS-RDPEDYC]: Remote Desktop Protocol: Dynamic Channel Virtual Channel Extension
[MS-RDPEFS]: Remote Desktop Protocol: File System Virtual Channel Extension
[MS-RDPEGDI]: Remote Desktop Protocol: Graphics Device Interface (GDI) Acceleration Extensions
[MS-RDPELE]: Remote Desktop Protocol: Licensing Extension
[MS-RDPEMC]: Remote Desktop Protocol: Multiparty Virtual Channel Extension
[MS-RDPEPC]: Remote Desktop Protocol: Print Virtual Channel Extension
[MS-RDPEPNP]: Remote Desktop Protocol: Plug and Play Devices Virtual Channel Extension
[MS-RDPEPS]: Remote Desktop Protocol: Session Selection Extension
[MS-RDPERP]: Remote Desktop Protocol: Remote Programs Virtual Channel Extension
[MS-RDPESC]: Remote Desktop Protocol: Smart Card Virtual Channel Extension
[MS-RDPESP]: Remote Desktop Protocol: Serial and Parallel Port Virtual Channel Extension
[MS-RDPEUSB]: Remote Desktop Protocol: USB Devices Virtual Channel Extension
[MS-RDPEV]: Remote Desktop Protocol: Video Redirection Virtual Channel Extension
[MS-RDPEXPS]: Remote Desktop Protocol: XML Paper Specification (XPS) Print Virtual Channel Extension
[MS-RDPNSC]: Remote Desktop Protocol: NSCodec Extension
[MS-RDPRFX]: Remote Desktop Protocol: RemoteFX Codec Extension
```

You can find all those here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc216513(v=PROT.10).aspx

With this documentation you can determine the feasibilty of your project.

Comment: Why is it crazy? The RDP enabled server would be listening on port 3389, so I'm sure I could emulate it with a socket...

Comment: RDP will give you graphics, let you contol the mouse and keyboard. Writing an app to do what you want to do really is crazy, and will be somewhat hard, its not like your connecting to a console and can run command dirrectly from it.

Comment: My point is emulating it will be hard...though possibly feasable. Doing anything useful and doing what you want is hard^2. It would be a cinch to do if you enabled SSH wrote your own PHP listener on the remote server. Thats what I would do!

Comment: I have to agree with Timothy Martens, whilst it might in theory be possible, it's utter madness to try and do this. SSH is a far far FAR more sensible option.

Answer (score 2):

I am using

```
rdesktop -u username -p password 192.168.1.131 -g 1024x640
```

in linux,
where 192.168.1.131 is the destination ip
and 1024x640 is the window size.

Also you can use

```
rdesktop -u username -p password 192.168.1.131 -f
```

for full screen.

Don't forget to replace the username and password with your details.

Comment: Please share your php code with me. Also Os version and apache2 version and php version.

Answer (score 0):

I think it be best if the servers were running a service that you could connect to. For example they could be running a web service (e.g. php if that's your desired language). You could then connect to that web address through port 80 which could run the applications. Of course you have security concerns, but you should be able to configure them so that they only accept requests from certain IPs. Alternatively you could make the script password-protected

Comment: That would work, but I have a LOT. It'd be a pain to set up an httpd on each of them.

Comment: You don't need to setup a web service, just create a PHP script that listens on a certain port.

Answer (score 0):

The reason ppl are not recommending RDP to do this is because RDP has no API to do even remotely what you actually want.
The easiest way to do this while somehow staying within your requirements, is to install one of the software linked below  on the host machines. Then you would need an API to connect:

- This: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/remoteexec.aspx. In PHP all you would need is something as simple as exec("rexec 123.21.61.12 notepad.exe "\fileserver1\test file.txt") (you can modify it to accept a key for a bit of security)
- TeamViewer (free): http://www.teamviewer.com/en/products/remotecontrol.aspx Then you would use TeamViewer WebConnect to connect to via PHP
- OpenVPN (open source) Not sure if there is an API that comes with it but I wouldn't be surprised
- Log me in (same as above)
- Install WAMP on the hosts and then have php run the commands on them. So it would be something like php to php where ur client would call something like curl(127.0.0.1/?key=loooong&command=blah) and the server would run exec("passed command")

Answer (score 0):

vmware Esxi uses such a ui page but not with PERL application, After reading the answers it seems a real challenge. I'm working on such a thing for my web based hosts access. If I get something done, I'll be happy to share with you.

https://labs.vmware.com/flings/esxi-embedded-host-client

Comment: did u get any thing helpful?

Answer (score -1):

Honestly, you're best bet would be C#. This probably isn't what you want to hear, but it's extremely trivial to make an rdp client in that language.

If you're allowed to create a user that has access to the logs. I'd make something that would run when the user is connected. The program would upload the logs to a unix server that has FTP access.

Then even if you can't write a one click solution in C# you could at least just login manually wait for the upload to be done then log out.

Comment: Perfect, write a small program in C# and then call it from PHP. Sounds like a good idea to me.

Comment: No one said write something in C# then call it from PHP. That would be asinine. Attempting to write an RDP client in PHP is equally as asinine which is why I suggested using C#. I suggest an alternate and better way of doing what he wanted to do and I get down voted for it. What's even funnier is I had to solve the same problem the OP is having. I solved with the above answer so I know for a fact it does work.  I wrote a RDP client in C# that would loop through a list of hosts, login, execute a command, and then logout.

Answer (score -1):

Why not running a perl script from a cronjob or execute the programs with the backquotes?

Answer (score -1):

If all you want to do is to connect to your many servers and run the same program, you could do a one-time upload of a php execute script to all your servers that should `exec()` a command from input data (most likely from `$_POST` or `$_GET`). You then write a local script, which will send the command string to run your program to all the exec scripts on all your servers, so essentially typing the command to run whatever program you need will execute the command on every server.

Obviously you'll need to require authentication for your exec script so nobody can abuse your servers. Of cause, this whole thing wouldn't be suitable if the program you're running requires much interaction (you did say you wanted to *run* a program, which implies you want to execute it and leave it to do it's own thing)

Answer (score -1):

Why not use FTP for what you need?
then generate and execute files with simple commands microsoft.

Answer (score -1):

I think it would be better to set up daemon/service on server to which you want connect and communicate with it via TCP. In this case, you are free to implement any protocol you want.